# Can I apply remote: true to an html href link?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I need an entire div to be a link, and the only way I've found to do that is to insert the div into a plain html href link.

But I also need the link to be remote. I made a guess:

```
<a href="www.link.com" remote=true>
  <div id='link'></div>
</a>
```

but while this syntax doesn't throw any errors, clicking on the link still opens a new page.

Is it possible to apply the Rails link method `remote: true` to an html href link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example of what I call "combining two right ways of doing something in the wrong way".

It's either you use your pure `html` and write a `javasript` script to give the div an `onclick` function, or you use the rubys' `link_to` and set `remote: true`: either of this should work fine for you

But combining these two is a no, as the included `remote: true` will not be interpretable.

```
<%= link_to "www.link.com", remote: true do %>
  <div></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: How would I use the ruby remote: true in this particular context?

Comment: I have added a code example to my answer post above

Answer (score 3):

according to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

you should use one of built in functions to generate remote href `<%= link_to "an article", @article, remote: true %>` which outputs with a bit different html in compare to yours `<a href="/articles/1" data-remote="true">an article</a>` (notice remote is a data attribute)